# Is this faucet supposed to be able to twist (on its vertical axis)

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink

I just moved into this house and I don't know what kind of faucet this is (no label anywhere).

The head of the faucet comes out, but the whole faucet is essentially stuck in the middle.  It gets annoying when I'm trying to wash things in the sink and want to move the faucet out of the way.  Do you guys know if this faucet is supposed to be able to move, and it's just stuck in its current place?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the manufacturer's name is on the back of the faucet stem at the bottom. You might try a mirror to see if it's there. Can't imagine a kitchen faucet not rotating unless it was installed improperly. You may have to pull it off and reinstall it.

Comment: It looks like there are pivot points see the white lines. Maybe they are tight, try making it turn from lower down not with the wand it may be tight, I could be wrong but I have had this type of faucet for over 30 years many different brands and they all would pivot.

Comment: I agree with Ed. Every faucet like this I've ever installed rotated. They usually have "O" rings inside and if they start to deteriorate they will freeze up  and make rotating the faucet difficult if not impossible. You might have to disassemble it and install new ones.

Comment: Alright, thanks everybody! I’ll try to disassemble and see if the o rings are in tact. Now to figure out how to disassemble this thing.....

Comment: Also you're right, the mfr name is on the back of the stem. Snapped a photo with my phone - looks like it's Kohler.